# Flutter bottomNavigationBar (change only body section)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Ok so I have got the following bottomNavigationBar working, however it's not clean enough for me and I am hoping there is a better way that someone knows.

Basically I only want to change the body section and not the full page.

However I want to have each section in different classes to keep it neat (ideally new .dart files - as they will all have different functions)

Currently all the page info is inside the body tag

```
 body: PageView(
      controller: _myPage,
      onPageChanged: (int) {
        print('Page Changes to index $int');
      },
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Text('Empty Body 0'),
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Text('images/pic1.jpg'),
              Text('images/pic2.jpg'),
              Text('images/pic3.jpg'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Text('Empty Body 2'),
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Text('DRN1 app is made using Google Flutter. While every attempt was made to make sure that this app works on as many devices as possible. We are unable to test every device. If you have issues running this app please let us know'),
          ),
        )
      ],
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // Comment this if you need to use Swipe.
    ),
```

what I would like is something like this.

```
body: PageView(
      controller: _myPage,
      onPageChanged: (int) {
        print('Page Changes to index $int');
      },
      children: <Widget>[
       home(),
news() , // this is the main body for home
shows(), // this one shows the class shows() which fetches JSON and returns a different body layout
about(), // about text
  ]
```

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is create separate ***Dart*** files and import them into your ***main.dart***

Then inside your ***State class*** define a list which contains the pages that you want to show

`List<Widget> _myPage = <Widget>[Page1class(),Page2class(),Page3class()];`


After that you can use the below code which looks quite clean. Using the `builder()` method will allow you to create pages based on the size of ***_myPage***,

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('sdf')),
    body: PageView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, position) => _myPage[position],
      itemCount: _myPage.length,
    ),
  )
);
```

Here is a sample program: [PageView sample](https://github.com/arbitrarymahi/SimpleFlutterExamples/tree/master/PageView)

Comment: any chance you have a full main.dart with an example - for the life of me I can't quite workout where List<Widget> goes.

Comment: Just wait I'll make a gist and share

Comment: https://github.com/arbitrarymahi/SimpleFlutterExamples/tree/master/PageView